# How to generate a list of variables that meet the conditions using the random module

Tags: python

My idea is as follows:

```
import random

list=[]
while True:
    A = random.uniform(0,3150) / 3150
    B = random.uniform(0,2200) / 2200
    C = random.uniform(0,1000) / 1000
    D = random.uniform(0,2600) / 2600
    E = random.uniform(0,2540) / 2540
    F = random.uniform(0,1200) / 1200
    G = random.uniform(0,1050) / 1050

    if A+B+C+D+E+F+G == 0.965:
        list[0] = A
        list[1] = B
        list[2] = C
        list[3] = D
        list[4] = E
        list[5] = F
        list[6] = G
        print(list)
        break
```

But even if I operate this code, it takes too long to get a list.
Should I

Comment: It's not clear what your conditions are. What are you expecting `random.uniform(0,3150) / 3150` to be? Why do you think numbers like that would *ever* add up to exactly `0.965`?

Comment: it is not sure that the problem has an exact solution... thus you could check rather abs(A+B+C+D+E+F+G - 0.965) <= 0.001 (or any other precision that suits you)

Comment: moreover in case of success your way to fill the list will fail, as list[0] is not yet defined. Try list=[A,B,C,D,D,E,F,G] instead

Comment: Oh I'm sorry.
The variable is volume, which is mass divided by density.
And the condition is, the sum of all the variables must be 0.965, the total volume.

Comment: As soon as you have determined A through F, the value for G is fixed by the condition that all values must sum to 0.965. You can only choose 6 of the 7 values at random. The 7th value is implied. It is "sort of random" since the other values are random. So instead of choosing G as random, you should set it to 0.965 - A - B - C - D - E - F.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to do it, using a generator

```
import random

def solution(precision):
    while True:
        A = random.uniform(0,3150) / 3150
        B = random.uniform(0,2200) / 2200
        C = random.uniform(0,1000) / 1000
        D = random.uniform(0,2600) / 2600
        E = random.uniform(0,2540) / 2540
        F = random.uniform(0,1200) / 1200
        G = random.uniform(0,1050) / 1050

        if abs(A+B+C+D+E+F+G - 0.965) <= precision:
            yield [A, B, C, D, E, F, G]
```

and you get values satisfying the condition by calling
`next(solution(0.001))` as many times as you need.

If you ask for a better precision, say 0.00001, it may take much longer to compute a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I dont understand why you're using `random.uniform(0, upperLim)/upperLim`because it will always be a value between 0 and 1. But if that is a necessary part of your implementation then go ahead. Otherwise change it to `random.uniform(0, 1)` because that avoids an unnecessary multiplication and gives you greater precision too.

To make sure the sum of the random numbers is 0.965 here's what you can do to avoid looping and checking multiple times:

Firstly change the upper limit from the one you specified to something that returns max 0.965 i.e, `random.uniform(0, 3150 * 0.965) / 3150`

After this, generate the numbers according to the conditions that have already been met

```
maxLists = 100
currLists = 0
while True:
    A = random.uniform(0, 0.965) # I'll use (0, 0.965) but you can replace it
    B = random.uniform(0, 0.965 - A)
    C = random.uniform(0, 0.965 - (A + B))
    D = random.uniform(0, 0.965 - (A + B + C))
    E = random.uniform(0, 0.965 - (A + B + C + D))
    F = random.uniform(0, 0.965 - (A + B + C + D + E))
    G = 0.965 - (A + B + C + D + E + F)

    # populate them into a list
    listOfNums = [A, B, C, D, E, F, G]

    # get numbers that are zero because we want to prevent only the first few numbers adding 
    # upto 0.965 all the time 
    zeros = [i for i, e in enumerate(listOfNums) if e == 0]
    nonZeros = [i for i, e in enumerate(listOfNums) if e != 0]
    
    # do something with numbers here, maybe randomly take some part of the value from
    # non zero indices and assign it to indices with zero value if you need the numbers
    # to have some minimum value or if you have some other constraint

    currLists += 1
    print(listOfNums)
    if currLists == maxLists: break
```

EDIT :

Here are some of the results I got after running it

```
[0.17790933642353207, 0.203575715409321, 0.17296325968456305, 0.12888905609400236, 0.07906382215736181, 0.19622480233464165, 0.006374007896577938]
[0.049602151767929197, 0.12732071710856213, 0.6719775449266687, 0.08616832676415115, 0.002068199017310945, 0.0015719942386102515, 0.026291066176767575]
[0.4216568638854053, 0.0841285730604016, 0.12581422942385648, 0.04125099314750179, 0.013789268384205427, 0.12463265303883869, 0.1537274190597907]
[0.39352655740635734, 0.08302194874949533, 0.05585858753600888, 0.14417023258593673, 0.17742466007873198, 0.042698164836977186, 0.06829984880649254]
[0.836553479500795, 0.019661470617368986, 0.06300565338226506, 0.021033910322500717, 0.0234921077113921, 0.0002043707861913963, 0.0010490076794867909]
[0.5334487166183782, 0.07743001493044013, 0.3431304879017562, 0.001616778025312949, 0.003948535326924425, 0.001755908717321748, 0.003669558479866386]
```

You can see the last few results are approaching zero, which is why you will either need to take some part of the previous values and add it to them or you can shuffle the numbers around randomly